# input's event.target is null within this.setState [React.js]

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In my react component I have a file input:

```
<input type="file" onChange={this.onFileChange.bind(this)} />`
```

and my `onFileChange` is:

```
onFileChange(e) {
  let file = e.target.files[0];
  this.setState(() => ({ file: e.target.files[0] })); //doesnt work
  // this.setState(() => ({ file })); //works
  // this.setState({ file: e.target.files[0] }); //works
}
```

This first way of setting the states fails with an error:

```
Cannot read property 'files' of null
```

React also gives the following warning:

```
This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're 
seeing this, you're accessing the property 'target' on a 
released/nullified synthetic event
```

But the last two ways of setting the state give no errors or warnings. Why is this happening?

Comment: Sorry im missing the point. Whats wrong with this.setState(() => ({ file })); that is the correct way to set state. I would also change let to const

Comment: @Zinc I was just curious why the first method didn't work! And I learned something new thanks to the responses :)

Comment: Declaring a variable `let file = e.target.files[0];` (line 2), you are creating the variable in a closure of an asynchronous function `() => ({ file })` (line 4). That is why it work.  Note that `e` is just an argument of `onFileChange` and it is not accessible in that asynchronous function (that is why `() => ({ file: e.target.files[0] })` does not work)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `setState` function is executed in asynchronous context.

By the time the state is updated the `e.target` reference might or might not be gone.

`const file = e.target.files[0];` can be used to "remember" the value as in your example.

Comment: Ahhh! Thanks. I didn't realize setState was asynchronous

Comment: The `file` variable is declared in the closure of a declaration of the `() => ({ file })` function that is why `file` is accessible by it later on.

Answer (score 4):

What is the reason for calling `setState` with callback ? `this.setState({ file: e.target.files[0] })` should do the job.

In your code you are referring to a synthetic event object which no longer holds information about the original DOM event. React reuses the event objects for performance reasons.

Alternatively you can use:

`let file = e.target.files[0];
const files = e.target.files
this.setState(() => ({ file: files[0] })); //doesnt work`

Comment: so `this.setState(() => {}) ` with an arrow function is asynchronous while `this.setState({})` is not? From the source I learned react form, I was told the former method is the standard. I didn't know it was async

Comment: I used the term unfortunately. All state updates in React are asynchronous. What I meant  by 'async' was actually passing updater callback instead of constructed object to `setState`. I think it is just an API difference and I find `setState({})` to be more readable. The `updater` callback must be used when you calculate new state based on the actual state (like incrementing). Reason why `setState(updater)` is mentioned in docs as first  maybe has to do with forcing people think it is an async operation which many tended to forgot (or did not know in first place).

Answer (score 3):

React uses event pooling, you can read more about it in the docs here https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

setState is an asynchronous function

```
this.setState(() => ({ file })); // is correct
```

Answer (score 2):

**Very simple/basic example to do the same task:**

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    file: ''
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
    <input type='file' onChange={(e) => {
    this.setState({file: e.target.files[0]}, () => {
        console.log('state', this.state);
    })
    }} />
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

I have added console log when the state will be set it will log the file details. You can see in the log when you select a file the state includes the file data.

*To see the console log you need to right click and inspect and see the Console.*

Checkout working example here https://jsfiddle.net/1oj3h417/2/

**Let me know if you have any doubt**

Comment: Thanks. I have a working version as you can see in the other two set state methods that are commented out. I posted because I'm curious why the first way doesn't work

Comment: its because react re-uses its event

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Example extends React.Component {

  onFileChange = e => {
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    this.setState(() => ({ file: file }));
  }
  render() {
    return <input type="file" onChange={this.onFileChange} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
</div>
```