# Run code after multiple methods resolve with Async and Await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I have three methods:

```
isSixCharactersLong(event) {
    const input_len = event.target.value.length;

    if (input_len === 6) {
        this.setState({isSixCharactersLong: true})
    } else {
        this.setState({isSixCharactersLong: false})
    }
}

isAlphanumeric(event) {
    const input_str = event.target.value;

    for (let i = 0; i < input_str.length; i++) {
        const code = input_str.charCodeAt(i);
        if (!(code > 47 && code < 58) && // numeric (0-9)
            !(code > 64 && code < 91) && // upper alpha (A-Z)
            !(code > 96 && code < 123)) { // lower alpha (a-z)
            this.setState({isAlphanumeric: true});
        } else {
            this.setState({isAlphanumeric: false});
        }
    }
}

isEmpty(event) {
    event.target.value ? this.setState({inputIsBlank: false}) : this.setState({inputIsBlank: true});
}
```

What I want to do is run a function after these three methods have resolved. So then I wrote the following:

```
async handleValidation(e) {
    this.isAlphanumeric(e);
    this.isEmpty(e);
    this.isSixCharactersLong(e);
}
```

And then I have this final method that gets triggered by my React application.

```
handleOnChange = async (e) => {
    await this.handleValidation(e)
        .then(() => this.setState({code: e.target.value}))
};
```

I would think this will work, but I keep getting an error that **e is null**. Somehow, I lose the **event**.

What I believe the problem is, it's that I'm not using async and await on the correct methods.

Comment: Why *is* `handleValidation` an `async` function? It doesn't `await` or `return` anything, and none of the functions it calls are async either.

Comment: There's no point of having async and await for non async functions...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input's event.target is null within this.setState \[React.js\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442839/inputs-event-target-is-null-within-this-setstate-react-js)

Comment: @AvinKavish that doesn't just magically happen if you write a promise, all of that code is synchronous anyway.

Comment: Hence the wink emoji at the end

Comment: This would be substantially more straightforward if you just called the validation functions with `event.target.value` and then `setState` once with the overall result: `handleOnChange = (e) => { const code = e.target.value; this.setState({ code, isSixCharactersLong: code.length === 6, /* don't even need a function for that one */, ...})};`

Comment: ^ The validation methods have no business being aware of the event, they should only be aware of the value they need to validate

Comment: *"I'm not using async and await on the correct methods"* - none of them need to be `async`, or `await`ed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Would you kindly explain a little bit more. I apologize. I'm kinda new using Async and await.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you're new to using them - you can just *not use them*. They're not helping you at all here. Just write vanilla functions, everything you're doing *except* what happens inside `setState` is synchronous right now.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ohh, so I don't even need to use them because this is all Synchronous code anyway. So then, if you can shed some light, how would you do it with normal vanilla javascript? Thank you Jon

Comment: that's due to [react's internal handling of synthetic events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling) you need to call `event.persist();` in order for it to keep a reference to the `target`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce this code down to,

```
handleOnChange = (e) => {
  const { value } = e.target
  const isAlphanumeric = /^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(value)
  const isSixCharactersLong = value && value.length === 6
  const inputIsBlank = !!value // or Boolean(value)

  this.setState({ isAlphanumeric, isSixCharactersLong, inputIsBlank })

  if (!inputIsBlank && isAlphanumeric && isSixCharactersLong)
    this.setState({ code: value })
}
```

`/^[a-z0-9]+$/i` : Regular expression to test for alphaumerics case insensitively

`!!`: Type coercion to boolean i.e. if value is empty it will be falsy, the double negation turns it into true and back to `false`

**Edit**

As per the discussion in the comments, in order to set `code` only if the input is valid, I have added an if statement which essentially translates into, if the value is not blank (`!inputIsBlank`) and if the value is alphanumeric and if the input is six characters long then set `code` to `value`.

Comment: Why not use `Boolean(value)` instead of `!!value`?

Comment: Personal preference. Why use `Boolean(value)` instead of `!!value` ?

Comment: `Boolean(value)` explicitly says construct a boolean representation of `value` - `!!value` is syntactic soup which does the same thing, but is also twice as many operations. The former also provides more consistency when you consider `Number(value)` instead of `+value` or `String(value)` instead of `"" + value`...

Comment: I love your code. I'm trying to save code just if the validations pass. That's why I put them in a bunch of methods. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes absolutely, let me make an edit. As for the `Boolean` being faster than `!!` it's far   more complicated than that, for example: the JIT could optimize `!!` directly into efficient machine code. Even if a benchmark reveals it to be true, I would still go with the simpler syntax over a few nano seconds of performance boost. The are both equally mentioned in the MDN docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean#Description I will not discuss this any further you are welcome to create your own question to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

You are using async await in both functions when nothing is a promise, this is all synchronous code, so you actually don't need async await to solve this problem. maybe write your validation code to throw an error if something doesn't pass and then inside of `handleOnChange` you can run a ternary

```
 handleOnChange = (e) => {
    !this.handleValidation(e)? return :
         this.setState({code: e.target.value}))
};
```