# React: saving selected options into state

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to save the selected options of my select box in state. I get an error when selecting something in my the box... It looks like "event" is not defined, which I don't see a reason why this should be the case.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'

class SwitchList extends React.Component{
  constructor(){ 
    super()
    this.state = {
      switches: [],
      selectedOption: []
    }
  }
  handleChange(event){
    this.setState({selectedOption: event.target.value })
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <Select
        value={this.state.selectedOption}
        options={this.state.switches}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    )
  }
}
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

Comment: To clarify did you mean "saving" by "safing"?

Comment: Actually it's target that appears to be undefined, not event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input's event.target is null within this.setState \[React.js\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442839/inputs-event-target-is-null-within-this-setstate-react-js)

Comment: Hi Bastian, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the first argument of `onChange` callback in `react-select` library is not an instance of React's `SyntheticEvent`. The first argument - is an option, that was selected. Also, you need to bind your `handleChange` function to `this` or use an arrow function. Here is a correct code:

```
constructor(){ 
    super()
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      switches: [],
      selectedOption: []
    }
  }

...
  handleChange(option){
    this.setState({selectedOption: option.value })
  }
...
```

And one advice. Use `console.log` or browser debugging tools if you not confident in a type or value of argument or variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issue's here.

First, you need to bind `this` to your `handleChange` function. For that you can use arrow function,

```
handleChange = (value) => {
   console.log(value)
   this.setState({selectedOption: value })
}
```

Second, `react-select` directly give you option in the format `{value: "", label: ""}` on change which you can directly set in state.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pyoq1v)