# React - unable to set state on input change

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am **not** new to react, but for some reason I am getting this error and I am unable to clear it out:

ERROR : Cannot read property 'value' of null

> Code :

```
const [platform, setPlatform] = React.useState(0);
  const [socialLinksState, setSocialLinksState] = useState({
    instagram: socialLinks?.instagram || "",
    linkedIn: socialLinks?.linkedIn || "",
    youtube: socialLinks?.youtube || "",
  });
  const socialLinksInputHandler = (e) => { 
    if (platform === 0) {
      setSocialLinksState((oldState) => ({
        ...oldState,
        instagram: e.target.value,  // <=== here (it says target is NULL)
      }));
    }
  };


// input field 

 <input
  onChange={(e) => socialLinksInputHandler(e)} //  <=== invoking the function
  value={
    platform === 0
              ? socialLinksState.instagram
              : platform === 1
              ? socialLinksState.linkedIn
              : platform === 2 && socialLinksState.youtube
  }
  placeholder={
    platform === 0
              ? "Instagram URL"
              : platform === 1
              ? "Linkedin Url"
              : platform === 2 && "Youtube Url"
  }
/>
```

I wonder what is it that I am missing here, thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this the answer you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47443091/8676647

Comment: Does this answer your question? [input's event.target is null within this.setState \[React.js\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442839/inputs-event-target-is-null-within-this-setstate-react-js)

Answer (score 0):

error is in bellow part

```
 value={
    platform === 0
              ? socialLinksState.instagram
              : platform === 1
              ? socialLinksState.linkedIn
              : platform === 2 && socialLinksState.youtube
  }
```

if socialLinksState or socialLinksState is undefined / null then it will throw error. to avoid that you can take help of lodash.

```
import _ from 'lodash'

...
...
...
 value={
        platform === 0
                  ? _.get(socialLinksState,'instagram','')
                  : platform === 1
                  ? _.get(socialLinksState,'linkedIn','')
                  : platform === 2 && _.get(socialLinksState,'youtube','')
      }
```

also avoid deep nested terinary operator and use *else if* inside render method and use the final value.